# Stream Analytics -> Master - Details

Tags: master-detail, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to create an Azure Stream Analytics select that will process json in this format:

```
{
"deviceid": "02060014440133F0",
"receivedat": "2017-02-24T10:16:50.9081833",
"messageid": "286eded6-dff1-4f6b-85be-ce4c3c050b69",
"telemetryvalues": [
  {
    "Name": "JUMPER1_2",
    "value": "0",
    "id": "9be40e7b-7589-4d88-af69-9a00bf71e203",
    "telemetryid": "a0259ae9-de01-47fb-9c0c-01fc72c85621",
    "scaledvalue": "0"
  },
  {
    "Name": "JUMPER1_2",
    "value": "2",
    "id": "837c4645-d13a-402f-9cf1-ac36b6bedef8",
    "telemetryid": "a0259ae9-de01-47fb-9c0c-01fc72c85621",
    "scaledvalue": "0,66"
  },
....
}
```

and insert it into two tables (Master - Detail)

I've created the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Telemetry](
  [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Telemetry_Id] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) NOT NULL,
  [DeviceId] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [MessageId] [varchar](40) NULL,
  [ReceivedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
  [CreatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TelemetryValues](
  [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT [DF_TelemetryValue_Id] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) NOT NULL,
  [TelemetryId] VARCHAR(40),
  [Name] VARCHAR(28),
  [Value] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  [ScaledValue] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  [CreatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL
```

My SA is very simple:

```
SELECT 
    *
INTO
    [TelemetryData]
FROM [DeviceData]
```

Where 'TelemetryData' points to my 'Telemetry' SQL table and 'DeviceData' to an eventhub with data.

However I'm not getting any data into my tables..... so I'm not really sure if SA can insert into two tables, or I'm doing something wrong...

N.B. If I try to store the data in a blob storage instead, then data are coming through, so it's not because of missing data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create several tables as several outputs of your ASA job. However I see your query only writes to one output (TelemetryData).

Also from what I see, no data is written in the SQL table because you have a mismatch between the result of your query schema and the schema of your table.

E.g. the output of SELECT * will be deviceid, receivedat, messageid, telemetrydata.

However the table you created have a different schema with different types.

When you use blobs, it used to work because blobs are not expecting a fixed schema. However with SQL, schema and types should match exactly.

Thanks,
JS - Azure Stream Analytics

Comment: The question was more if it was possible to insert into a two tables (master - details) from one SELECT, so that a foreign constraint between the two tables doesn't fail